# using BButton fontawsome icons don't show properly? Wierd icon displays instead

Tags: iphone, ios, font-awesome

I am trying to use the `BButton` library with the following code :-

```
 BButton *btn = [[BButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 40)];
 [btn setType:BButtonTypeDanger];
 [btn setTitle:@"Browse Manufacturers" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [btn addAwesomeIcon:FAIconBookmark beforeTitle:YES];
 [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

I added it to my project using cocopods like I do with every other library I use.  I installed FontAwesome font on my mac and I am able to use it in other programs like Adobe although I do not see it as an option in `xCode`.

Instead of seeing the icons I see some weird icon instead: [image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag FontAwesome.otf to your project.

Add "Fonts Provided by Application" and set value in one item to "FontAwesome.otf"

Comment: In my case the file included in BButton was "FontAwesome.ttf". I followed these instructions with that file instead of the .otf version and it worked perfectly.